# Using SVG to create separate images files

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I've previously processed XSLT to output single HTML files that were supposed to be viewed in a browser.

Now I was hoping if someone could outline would it be possible to use XML data and XSLT to create separate image files auto magically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XSLT processor supports EXSLT, the [exsl:document](http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html) element will allow you to create multiple output files from a single input file.

AFAIK, only [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/)-based processors support this tag, currently, but this includes [PHP 5](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) and, of course, xsltproc.

**EDIT:**

As you've found, XSLT 2.0 provides the similar [xsl:result-document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document) tag.  The XSLT 2.0 processors I'm aware of are [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/), [Altova XML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html), and [Gexslt/Gestalt](http://www.gobosoft.com/eiffel/gobo/gexslt/).

Comment: I've checked it. This can work, as can the xsl:result-document element (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document). Well I guess this is one less mystery then :)

Comment: Many XSLT 1.0 processors have support for XSLT -- saying this is only libxslt is not true. Also, the current XSLT 2.0 processors are actually three: Saxon, Altova and Gexslt (or Gestalt).

Comment: @Dimitre — I was referring specifically to the `exsl:document` tag, not EXSLT in general. If you know of others, I'd be happy to add them.